# Phonegap/Cordova Touch Id Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to setup Touch Id in my phonegap app using 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id but i'm having no luck

I am installing it using cordova CLI.

I've tried everything I've seen in the documentation and internet but still no luck, i'm not sure if i'm missing something.

When I tried putting this code in my HTML and view it in browser, the plugin is loaded but not when viewing it in the actual phonegap app.

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable(function(msg) {alert('ok: ' + msg)}, function(msg) {alert('not ok: ' + msg)})">Touch ID available?</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.touchid.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please', function(msg) {alert('ok: ' + msg)}, function(msg) {alert('not ok: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))})">Scan fingerprint</button>
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to do, where does it fail, what is the error message, what have you tried?

Comment: it fails straight away, when viewing it in browser the plugin is being loaded but when viewing it in the phonegap app the plugin is not being loaded.

Comment: What device and OS are you testing it on?

Comment: I'm testing it on iPhone 6

Comment: yes, i'm using iOS9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122519/discussion-between-maion-and-thomcunningham).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem, if you are installing it using npm

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-touch-id
$ cordova prepare
```

or github

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id
$ cordova prepare
```

you still need add the plugin in your config.xml

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-touch-id" source="npm" spec="~3.2.0" />
```

Hope this will help.